# How to install SRFI-19 with Chicken 4.8.0.3?

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

How can I install SRFI-19 with Chicken 4.8.0.3? Using `sudo chicken-install srfi-19` fails.

After some experimentation, I found I needed to run `sudo chicken-install setup-helper` first, yet I remain stuck. The output I receive is

```
retrieving ...connecting to host "chicken.kitten-technologies.co.uk", port 80 ...
requesting "/henrietta.cgi?name=srfi-19&mode=default" ...
reading response ...
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 23 May 2013 17:00:04 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/0.9.9-dev DAV/2 SVN/1.7.8 PHP/5.4.13 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/plain
reading chunks ....
reading files ...
  ./TODO
  ./chicken-primitive-object-inlines.scm
  ./de/
  ./de/srfi-19
  ./en/
  ./en/srfi-19
  ./es/
  ./es/srfi-19
  ./it/
  ./it/srfi-19
  ./nl/
  ./nl/srfi-19
  ./pt/
  ./pt/br/
  ./pt/br/srfi-19
  ./srfi-19-common.scm
  ./srfi-19-core.scm
  ./srfi-19-date.scm
  ./srfi-19-io.scm
  ./srfi-19-period.scm
  ./srfi-19-support.scm
  ./srfi-19-time.scm
  ./srfi-19-timezone.scm
  ./srfi-19.meta
  ./srfi-19.scm
  ./srfi-19.setup
  ./tai-utc.dat
 srfi-19 located at /tmp/temp9ecf.57778/srfi-19
checking platform for `srfi-19' ...
checking dependencies for `srfi-19' ...
install order:
("srfi-19")
installing srfi-19:3.3.4 ...
changing current directory to /tmp/temp9ecf.57778/srfi-19
  /opt/local/bin/csi -bnq -setup-mode -e "(require-library setup-api)" -e "(import setup-api)" -e "(setup-error-handling)" -e "(extension-name-and-version '(\"srfi-19\" \"3.3.4\"))" -e "(sudo-install #t)" /tmp/temp9ecf.57778/srfi-19/srfi-19.setup
  sudo cp -r de/srfi-19 /opt/local/lib/chicken/6/srfi-29-bundles/de/srfi-19
  sudo cp -r en/srfi-19 /opt/local/lib/chicken/6/srfi-29-bundles/en/srfi-19
  sudo cp -r es/srfi-19 /opt/local/lib/chicken/6/srfi-29-bundles/es/srfi-19
  sudo cp -r it/srfi-19 /opt/local/lib/chicken/6/srfi-29-bundles/it/srfi-19
  sudo cp -r nl/srfi-19 /opt/local/lib/chicken/6/srfi-29-bundles/nl/srfi-19
  sudo cp -r pt/br/srfi-19 /opt/local/lib/chicken/6/srfi-29-bundles/pt/br/srfi-19
  /opt/local/bin/csc -feature compiling-extension -setup-mode    srfi-19-timezone.scm -shared -optimize-leaf-routines -inline -output-file srfi-19-timezone.so -emit-import-library srfi-19-timezone -emit-inline-file srfi-19-timezone.inline -emit-type-file srfi-19-timezone.types -fixnum-arithmetic -optimize-level 3 -no-procedure-checks

Error: shell command terminated with non-zero exit status 10: /opt/local/bin/chicken srfi-19-timezone.scm -output-file srfi-19-timezone.c -dynamic -feature chicken-compile-shared -feature compiling-extension -setup-mode -optimize-leaf-routines -inline -emit-import-library srfi-19-timezone -emit-inline-file srfi-19-timezone.inline -emit-type-file srfi-19-timezone.types -fixnum-arithmetic -optimize-level 3 -no-procedure-checks

Error: shell command failed with nonzero exit status 256:

  /opt/local/bin/csc -feature compiling-extension -setup-mode    srfi-19-timezone.scm -shared -optimize-leaf-routines -inline -output-file srfi-19-timezone.so -emit-import-library srfi-19-timezone -emit-inline-file srfi-19-timezone.inline -emit-type-file srfi-19-timezone.types -fixnum-arithmetic -optimize-level 3 -no-procedure-checks


Error: shell command terminated with nonzero exit code
17920
"/opt/local/bin/csi -bnq -setup-mode -e \"(require-library setup-api)\" -e \"(im...
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[Note: I have filed a bug report with the Chicken bug tracker. However, I am hoping others have seen this problem before and/or know how to work around it.]

Comment: I think it is because you are asking a question not directly related to programming. If you have problem installing a program, or library it may be better of asking over at superusers. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: trying to installing a compiler is not programming...

Comment: @Xarcell: That sounds a bit of a stretch, especially in light of the fact the FAQ states, "What kind of questions can I ask here? ... [I]f your question generally covers ... software tools commonly used by programmers ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: @xuinkrbin. Please don't destroy the content in your question. Just let it be. Doing so repeatedly is frowned upon. FYI, the question is under discussion at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181597/question-about-installing-a-compiler-interpreter-for-a-programming-language-of

Comment: @Bart: While I appreciate the sentiment and Your vote in favor of this being "on topic", I just feel frustrated with SO in general due to what appears to be an all-too-trigger-happy reaction on the part of a set of Individuals to simply mark a question as "off topic". While it may only be a case of "confirmation bias", I seem to be seeing such cases more and more frequently on SO and I think it degrades the usefulness/reputation of the site. Thanks again.

Comment: @xuinkrbin. If there is ever any confusion as to whether or not your question should have been closed, just come to Meta and ask us to explain the situation. The site isn't perfect. Sometimes stuff gets closed too soon, or when it shouldn't have been closed at all. Sometimes the problem is easily addressed. And other times stuff stays open that doesn't belong on the site. It happens. Don't take it too harsh though. I hope you'll get your answer.

Comment: @Bart: Thanks. While I know the site is not perfect, I guess I would have appreciated a more helpful approach than what comes across as telling a User, "Hey, I say You've broken the rules; get lost."

Answer (score 0):

The ticket which was filed by the OP has been marked "fixed", so I guess it's no longer an issue. See https://bugs.call-cc.org/ticket/1013